# Lost keyboard shortcut for beginning-of-line/end-of-line

Tags: macos, keyboard

After purchasing a new computer (Mac Mini w/Lion) and migrating my settings from old one (Macbook Pro w/Snow Leopard), the system shortcuts for beginning-of-line and end-of-line text navigation commands (Cmd-left/right arrow) just don't work anymore, anywhere.

Curiously, this happens only in a single user account, and in other accounts on the same computer it's OK. Other shortcuts with the Command key (like Cmd-up) also work just fine.

I have browsed through the keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences > Keyboard. I also have KeyRemap4Macbook installed and browsed through its settings, to no avail. There is no Keybindings folder in my ~/Library, either.

Anybody have any idea how to even start debugging this problem?

Comment: See also [Command+right/left stopped working](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23775/commandright-left-stopped-working). (It's not an exact duplicate since the problem was that the shortcuts stopped working only occasionally.)

Comment: Thanks for the link to that question! It made me browse through the system shortcuts again, and lo and behold - Cmd+Left & Cmd+Right were indeed in plain sight as shortcuts for "Move Left a Space" and "Move Right a Space" - I didn't even look there before because I did not use Spaces at all in Snow Leo, and so I assume these shortcuts were inactive. Now the upgrade to Lion and Mission Control activated them, but I still had only one space so they did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I remember having the same problem in *some* apps after upgrading to Lion. A reboot fixed it for me.

Workaround: use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>) to move the cursor to the beginning of the line and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to move the cursor to the end of the line (instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>). This works in all Cocoa-based applications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know of the workaround but of course it would be nice to be able to go back to the shortcuts that are in my muscle memory after so many years...

Comment: Did you try a reboot? Did you use Software Update until you’re on the latest version (10.7.3)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I have restarted a couple of times already since first noticing this symptom. I'm also upgraded to the latest Lion available, 10.7.3.

Comment: Usually the **⌘** key is represented as **@** in dictionary files. It might help running `grep -I "@" ~/Library/Preferences/*` and you might find some settings that are not listed in the Keyboard Preferences. The -I option in the command tells it to ignore binary files, in case you are not familiar with this.

Comment: Note: ⌃A and ⌃E are not equivalent to ⌘← and ⌘→. The former go to the beginning/end of the whole line (paragraph), while the latter take word-wrapping into account in Cocoa text fields.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the commenter Lri for pointing to this question: [Command+right/left stopped working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23775/commandright-left-stopped-working)! It made me browse through the system shortcuts again, and lo and behold - Cmd+Left & Cmd+Right were indeed in plain sight as shortcuts for "Move Left a Space" and "Move Right a Space" - I didn't even look there before because I did not use Spaces at all in Snow Leo, and so I assumed these shortcuts were inactive. Now the upgrade to Lion and Mission Control activated them, but I still had only one space so they did nothing.

So it was enough to actually redefine them to something else to regain the beginning/end-of-line functionality.

Sorry everyone for misleading with the wrong information (turns out I did not actually browse through *all* possible shortcuts...)