# Left Shift and Left Command combination yields only Left Command; other shift command combos work fine

Tags: macos, keyboard

Early 2011 15" Macbook Pro, Lion, no external keyboard or mouse:

Lately I noticed that I can't use <kbd>left-shift</kbd>+<kbd>left-command</kbd> together; it registers as <kbd>left-command</kbd> only.  The other three combinations (<kbd>right-shift</kbd>+<kbd>right-command</kbd>, <kbd>right-shift</kbd>+<kbd>left-command</kbd>, <kbd>left-shift</kbd>+<kbd>right-command</kbd>) work properly. I’ve confirmed this in text editors and in the keyboard viewer.

Same problem appears with <kbd>left-command</kbd>+<kbd>left-control</kbd>.

I’ve shut down all programs, verified no weird keybinds in Universal Access or elsewhere, even installed Lion to a clean external disk and booted from that.  The first thing I did was check <kbd>left-shift</kbd> and <kbd>left-command</kbd> in TextEdit; same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: same problem... did you eventually figure it out?

Comment: I'd forgotten about this question, saw the notice on my profile, checked, and the problem is gone.  In the meantime I've reinstalled, upgraded to Maverick, and moved from the midwest to the west coast.  If anyone happens to test those three in isolation please report back!

Comment: this problem started a week ago, and i was already a maverick user for a few months before it happened. I live in Israel..... I doubt your geographical location has anything to do with it.

Comment: I suppose you've checked related answers, but does anything in this help?  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23775/commandright-left-stopped-working?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the non-answer of "I reinstalled OSX and upgraded to Maverick from Lion, and it now works" because, well, it now works. Unfortunately I don't know what were the actual reasons it broken and then un-broken. I am sorry to anyone whom this question didn't help at all.

If anyone else comes up with a reasonable explanation I'll mark them as the answer instead.