# Left modifier keys don't work as expected, while right keys work as they should

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

#### Question

I have the issue that standard keyboard combinations - such as <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> for selecting text - on the left side of my keyboard don't work - or only on second try - in standard applications such as TextEdit or Safari. It is not possible to select single characters or whole words.

The same modifier keys on the right side of the keyboard work as they should.

First I thought that my keyboard (hardware) was broken. But it seems to be a software issue. Maybe there are programs (e.g. TextEdit and Safari) that both use conflicting keyboard combinations?

All possible key combinations were tested, including for example left shift +t. I borrowed and experimented with some (original Apple) external keyboard. It had the same issues, which made me think it is a software - not hardware - issue

#### What I've tried

- Using an external keyboard. Same issues.
- Installing a keyboard tester ([Inspect](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Inspect)). Keyboard works fine.
- Check System Preferences —> Keyboard  —> Modifier Keys. No conflicting settings.
- Installed [ShortcutDetective](https://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/), which I can't get working

Any clues on how I can make the left modifier keys work again?

MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) - Big Sur 11.4 - no external keyboard in use

Comment: So.. shift/alt does what you expect if you use the right side keys, just not the left side?

Comment: yes it does work on the right side, but not the left side

Comment: When you say "Keyboard works fine" with the keyboard tester. What do you mean? Do the left modifier keys light up in the Inspect app when you press them?
Does the left shift work on it's own? I.e. can you write a capital T by pressing left shift + t? Does the left alt work on it's own? I.e. when you press left alt + right arrow, does the insertion point move to the end of the next word?

Comment: Which speicifc Mac model do you use (and which keyboard, if external)?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke"Keyboard works fine": all possible key combinations were tested, including your examples.

I borrowed and experimented with some (original Apple) external keyboard. It had the same issues, which made me think it is a software - not hardware - issue

@nohillside MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) - Big Sur 11.4 - no external keyboard in use

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Could you please edit your question with new information? Comments might get deleted and are not "long term". Also, can you check [previous](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/23775/24324) similar question on the topic of left/right modifier keys not working? Please report any things you try in the question such that answerers won't suggest you those things anymore.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/425811//182183 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/417883/182183 seem similar. Unfortunately, they don't seem to be very helpful.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/201099/182183 says reinstalling macOS helped, except it's still Mac OS X at that point and the problem has apparently been going on for a while.